# firstore query skips all documents with same startAfter value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

TLDR; firestore skips all the documents that has same `startAfter` value. How to overcome this limitation.

My firestore postLikers collections keeps a document for each person who liked my post.
It stores the UID of the liker, and the epoch timestamp of when the post was liked.

```js
postLikersCol : [
  doc_1 : { uid: uid1, timeOfLike: 1661924000 },
  doc_2 : { uid: uid2, timeOfLike: 1661924001 },
  doc_3 : { uid: uid3, timeOfLike: 1661924002 }, // same time
  doc_4 : { uid: uid4, timeOfLike: 1661924002 }, // same time
  doc_5 : { uid: uid5, timeOfLike: 1661924002 }, // same time
  doc_6 : { uid: uid6, timeOfLike: 1661924003 },
  doc_7 : { uid: uid7, timeOfLike: 1661924004 },
]
```

and I am readin the data like this :

```js
firestore()
.collection('postLikersCol')
.orderBy('timeOfLike', 'desc')
.startAfter(lastReadDoc.timeOfLike)
.limit(3)
.get()
```

In the first round of query the `.startAfter()` is not added so I get last 3 docs (`doc_7`, `doc_6`, `doc_5`, in this order)\

In the second call, `.startAfter()` is added in query and it takes `timeOfLike` of the last read document (`doc_5`) i.e. `1661924002`
With this call, the firestore returns `doc_2` and `doc_1`, both of which has `timeOfLike` < `1661924002`

With this scenario, `doc_4` and `doc_3` are never read !!

Can someone suggest a solution for this, that I can read all documents with `.orderBy('timeOfLike', 'desc')`

---

Only solution I thought is using unique `orderBy` fields.
So appending `uid` with `timestamp` may work (`1661924002_uid3`).
Is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `startAfter()` with `DocumentSnapshot` of last document instead of the timestamp value. Try:

```
const snap = await firestore()
  .collection('postLikersCol')
  .orderBy('timeOfLike', 'desc')
  .startAfter(lastReadDocSnap)
  .limit(3)
  .get()
```

Here, `lastReadDocSnap` would be `snap.docs[3]` i.e. the last document of previous query.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I found that that i can give two orderBy and two startAfter, to overcome this issue.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#set_cursor_based_on_multiple_fields

I suppose it will require a compound index (additional cost overhead)
But the solution of appending uid to the timestamp also costs more storage, and lengthier data is stored and it's not a number anymore.

Hmm, If you still have a better answer please let me know.